# No puedo enviar (hacer el push) de lo que está en mi rama de Git, a la rama master (main)

Tags: git, github

Tengo un repositorio compartido con compañeros en GitHub, y cada uno tiene su propia rama y trabajamos en ellas, la cosa es que todo lo que tengo yo en mi rama, quiero ahora subirlo a la rama master o la rama main,

1. Yo hago git add . para agregar todos los cambios
2. Git commit (todo esto en mi rama)
3. Ahora git checkout main (me cambia a la rama main)
4. Ahí hago el git push origin main.

Pero tengo el siguiente error y no me deja hacer nada, solo puedo hacer push a mi propia rama.

```
D:ruta del repositorio>git push origin main
To https://github.com/repoFicticio/ProyectoFicticio
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repoFicticio/ProyectoFicticio'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

¿Alguna idea? Por si os lo preguntáis, estamos iniciándonos todos los compas en git, y aún no lo manejamos bien bien :p

Comment: Segun esta página este puede ser tu problema, La punta de su rama actual está detrás de su contraparte remota” significa que ha habido cambios en la rama remota que no tiene localmente.
https://codewithhugo.com/fix-git-failed-to-push-updates-were-rejected/
Suele haber 2 tipos de cambios en la rama remota: alguien agregó confirmaciones o alguien modificó el historial de la rama (generalmente algún tipo de rebase).

Comment: Si trabajas en tu propia rama (distinta de main), al hacer push origin main no estarías subiendo tus cambios, a menos que antes hubieras hecho un merge o rebase de tu rama con main. Por otro lado, el que el push te falle indica que tu rama main tiene commits que el remoto no tiene, pero también el remoto tiene commits que tú no tienes. Debes comenzar por tener en tu rama lo que tenga el remoto, para lo cual la solución suele ser un git pull. Prepárate no obstante a posibles conflictos (ficheros modificados tanto en remoto como en local)

Comment: Aunque @abulafia ya explicó algunas de las cosas que vas a tener que hacer, quiero comentar sobre un concepto en el que creo que hay un fallo. Tu rama main no debería ser diferente de la rama main del remoto (a menos que **sepas** lo que estas haciendo). Si haces checkout de main **local**, antes de intentar empujar esa rama al remoto, **tienes** que primero halas los cambios del remoto con un `git pull`. Nota aparte es que si usan flujos que utilicen PRs para meter los cambios en main, en ese caso **no se debe** hacer push directamenye a main.

Comment: Si tu rama main de GitHub tiene commits que tu main no, y trabajaste en otra rama desprendida de tu main, puede que tengas cambios que no sean totalmente compatibles en tu rama nueva. Intenta en tu main: **git pull —ff-only** y, si funciona bien, **git merge —no-ff tu-rama** para meter los cambios nuevos, y **git push** para subir a GitHub.

Comment: Otra opción (creo que más sensata) es **git checkout tu-rama** y intentar **git rebase origin/main**, ahí podes tener conflictos, y ya resueltos es solo  **git checkout main** y **git merge tu-rama**, eso te deja para un fast forward cuando hacés push a GitHub.

Comment: Voy a intentar todo lo que decís, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Se me olvidó postear que mi fallo, lo tenemos todos los integrantes del grupo, que solo podemos pushear a nuestras ramas. La opción B va a ser crear un repositorio nuevo y subir al main todos los cambios, un poco chapuzas lo sé.

Comment: La forma en la que se trabaja normalmente en github es empujando las ramas que _no_ son main al repositorio remoto y crear PRs (`Pull Requests`) solicitando mezclar dichas ramas en main (lo cual arranca un flujo de revisión por parte de los otros desarrolladores que trabajan en el proyecto).